# Inequality in the eigenvalues of $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, matrix-analysis

Suppose $B \in M_{n \times n} (\mathbb C)$ is Hermitian. Prove that $$\lambda_{min}\leq b_{kk} \leq \lambda_{max}, \; \text{for}\; 1 \leq k \leq n.$$ With the equality in both sides for some $k$ only if $b_{kj}=b_{jk}=0,$ for all $k\neq j.$ Here $\lambda_{min} \;\& \; \lambda_{max}$ are the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of $B$ and $b_{kj}$ is the $(k,j)$- entry of $B$. 
 
 Attempt: Using Rayleigh-Ritz theorem we achieved the inequalities above. How can I show the equality in both sides if $b_{kj}=b_{jk}=0,$ does it follow from Rayleigh-Ritz? Also suppose we take the matrix $\text{diag}(1,2,3)$
does the condition $b_{kj}=b_{jk}=0,$ for all $k\neq j$ imply that $b_{kk}$ is equal to either $\lambda_{min} \;\vee \; \lambda_{max}?$ 
Any help and hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from Rayleigh Ritz. In particular: part of the Rayleigh Ritz theorem states that if $x$ is a unit vector with $x^*Bx = \lambda_{\max}$, then it must hold that $x$ is an eigenvector of $B$ associated with $\lambda_\max$. Now, note that if $b_{kk} = \lambda_{\max}$, then then the vector $x = e_k$ (the $k$th standard basis vector) satisfies $x^*Bx = \lambda_\max$. Similar logic can be applied in the case that $b_{kk} = \lambda_\min$.

Comment: Yup I already prove that part, what I dont know is the equality part does it follow from rayleigh ritz?

Comment: Yes, the second sentence of my answer is part of Rayleigh Ritz

Comment: Sorry can you enlighten me a bit, I dont get the part where the equality holds specially if $b_{kj}=b_{jk}=0,$ for all $k \neq j$. Also about my example does it holds? Or is it wrong?

Comment: @TokitaOhma It seems that you misinterpreted the phrase "only if". Equality holds "only if" $b_{kj} = b_{jk} = 0$ means that equality can only hold if $b_{jk} = b_{kj} = 0$. In other words: the statement is "if equality holds, then (there exists a $k$ such that for all $j \neq k$) $b_{jk} = b_{kj} = 0$".

Comment: My bad sorry about that. Sorry for my dumbness, so the example  doesnt holds?

Comment: @TokitaOhma The statement after your example is a bit too imprecise to say that it either "holds" or "doesn't hold". In your example, it is not true that $b_{kk} = \lambda_\min$ or $b_{kk} = \lambda_\max$ holds for every $k$, which is the statement that you seem interested in. In particular, $b_{22}$ is not equal to $\lambda_\min$ or $\lambda_\max$. It is true, however, that there exists a $k$ such that $b_{kk} = \lambda_\min$ and there exists a $k$ such that $b_{kk} = \lambda_\max$.

Comment: @TokitaOhma And you have nothing to apologize for. If everybody understood math perfectly the first time, there wouldn't be much reason for this website.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess that solves it.

Comment: @TokitaOhma You're welcome. By the way, your statement was perfectly fine; I realize now that I just read it incorrectly. The statement does not hold for your example.