# Proof of the upper bound

Tags: matrices

Suppose $B \in M_{n \times n} (\mathbb C)$ is Hermitian. Prove that $$\lambda_{\min}\leq b_{kk} \leq \lambda_{\max}, \text{ for } 1 \leq k \leq n.$$ With the equality in both sides for some $k$ only if $b_{kj}=b_{jk}=0,$ for all $k\neq j.$ Here $\lambda_{\min} \;\& \; \lambda_{\max}$ are the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of $B$ and $b_{kj}$ is the $(k,j)$- entry of $B$.

I already cracked a proof for the lower bound using Rayleigh's theorem but got confused on how to show that it is bounded above by $\lambda_{\max}$. Do we use same approach as to the lower bound? Please someone give me a heads up. Thanks.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4073439/81360)

Comment: This is what I did for the lower bound:

We show that $\lambda_{\min}=\min_{x\neq 0}\frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}$. Let $P$ be a unitary matrix and $D$ a diagonal matrix such that $P^*DP=A$. We have $$x^*Ax=x^*P^*DPx=(Px)^*DPx$$ and $(Px)^*Px=x^*x$ hence 
 $$\min_{x\neq 0}r(x)=\min_{x\neq 0}\frac{\langle Dx,x\rangle}{\langle x,x\rangle}.$$
 It can be gleaned that $\min_{x\neq 0}r(x)\geq \lambda_{\min}$. Notice that $a_{jj}=r(e_j)$, where $e_j$ is the $j$-th element of the canonical basis of $\mathbb C^n$. So $a_{jj}=r(e_j)\geq \min_{x\neq 0}r(x)\geq \lambda_{\min}$.

Comment: Is the proof for the upper bound similar?